# How to get the first 2 character of a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that contains 2 numbers in front, followed by a dash and a words

- 01 - Borrower
- 02 - Co-borrower
- 03 - Guarantor

How can I go about only taking the numbers from the string and saving it to a variable or string to use for later?

I want to be able to store 01, 02, 03, etc. as a string

Comment: What have you tried? (I'd also advise against just getting the first two characters and instead just get the first characters that are digits)

Comment: Take a look on split and substrings and decide what better suits you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are number of ways you could do it.  Tim's answer is one. Another would be to use:

```
var number = str.Substring(0,2);
```

Another option would be to use a regular expression

```
var number = Regex.Match(str, @"(\d{2}) -").Groups[1].Value;
```

it really all depends on how performant you want it to be and how likely you are to have variations in the input data.  If it is always going to be the first two characters, I would use Substring.  If it is going to be more variable, I would use a regular expression.

Comment: Substring was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

One way: `String.Split`

```
string number = str.Split('-')[0].Trim();
```

other way, `String.Substring` and `IndexOf` (more efficient if the string is very large):

```
int dashIndex = str.IndexOf('-');
if(dashIndex != -1)
    number = str.Substring(0, dashIndex).Trim();
```

or `String.Remove`(also uses `Substring` internally):

```
if(dashIndex != -1)
    number = str.Remove(dashIndex).Trim();
```